# ORDER BY not working correctly on calculated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to create a table with the Top 1000 entities by a certain value. I am trying to create the table in one query. I cannot share my data, but my query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [A], [B], [C],
    SUM([QTY]) AS Total_QTY
INTO 
    [db].[TopThousandEntities]
FROM 
    [db].[dt]
WHERE 
    [B] NOT LIKE '%Thing'
GROUP BY 
    [A], [B], [C]
ORDER BY 
    SUM([QTY]) DESC
```

What is happening is that my data is returned like this:

```
A    B    C  Calculated
------------------------
X    Y    Z    100
D    E    F     89
```

.... next 200-300 are correct i.e. descending in value... then

```
Q    R    T    92
E    I    U    88
O    U    Z    83
```

And the problem repeats in cycles until row 1000. Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: It's because of your `GROUP BY`.  It groups, then orders within those groups.

Comment: right, forgot about that. thanks. is there a work around, off the top of your head? i need to group by for accurate totals

Comment: move the ordering to an outer select.  `SELECT * FROM ( your current query without the ordering)x ORDER BY x.Total_Qty DESC`

Comment: @devlincarnate . . . Neither of your comments make sense.  The `ORDER BY` applies to the entire result set.

Comment: @bhbennett3 . . . I think you are misinterpreting your results somehow.  For instance, you have given the column a name in the query, but that is not the name in your sample data.  You should show the query you are using to get the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are checking the data using:

```
select *
from [db].[TopThousandEntities];
```

**SQL tables represent unordered sets.**  There is no ordering unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

So, if you want to see them in order:

```
select *
from [db].[TopThousandEntities]
order by Total_QTY desc;
```

If you want to preserve the original ordering in the table, you can add an identity column:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) IDENTITY(int) as TopThousandEntities_id,
       [A], [B], [C],
       SUM([QTY]) AS Total_QTY
INTO  [db].[TopThousandEntities]
FROM [db].[dt]
WHERE [B] NOT LIKE '%Thing'
GROUP BY [A], [B], [C]
ORDER BY SUM([QTY]) DESC;
```

You can now order by the identity column instead:

```
select *
from [db].[TopThousandEntities]
order by TopThousandEntities;
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know this about SQL. So it is safe to presume that the top 1000 entities (by quantity) were selected, regardless of how my "check" ```select * from [db].[TopThousandEntities]``` returns?

Comment: @bhbennett3 . . . There would be a significant bug in SQL Server if it did NOT return the top 1000 entities by quantity.  I am guessing that after 20+ years in Microsoft's hands, this code has been pretty thoroughly tested and debugged.  This answer seems like a much more likely explanation than a bug.

Comment: Lol thank you. Big learning experience - the issue was not my coding of the table creation query, but the coding of my validation query!

Answer (score 1):

The grouping is applied before the ordering.  To get the ordering your want, assuming you also want the `TOP` to be with regard to the Total_qty, move `ORDER BY` and `TOP` to an outer select clause, like so:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) c.*
FROM (
   SELECT 
        [A]
        ,[B]
        ,[C]
        ,SUM([QTY]) AS Total_QTY
    FROM [db].[dt]
    WHERE [B] NOT LIKE '%Thing'
    GROUP BY [A]
        ,[B]
        ,[C]
    ) x
ORDER BY x.Total_QTY DESC
```

Comment: don't you have to move the top and into into the outside query?

Comment: It depends...  If the desire is to get the TOP entities according to the Total_Qty, then yes.

Comment: Yes, I think I need ```SELECT TOP (1000) x.* INTO [db].[TopThousandEntities] FROM``` .... this was helpful, thank you

Comment: Had to remove "selected as answer." SQL Server Manager Studio will not run with `INTO` inside of the sub-query. Having it outside (my way) is still producing the same problem. I don't think `GROUP BY` is the issue, as there are few if any repeating elements in columns A, B, or C

Comment: When I remove `INTO` from the query everything runs correctly however. Just doesn't create the table.

Comment: @devlincarnate . . . This answer is nonsense.  I realize that is rather direct, but the ordering is applied after the group by *and that is what the OP wants*.  The query is the same, regardless of whether or not the aggregation is in a subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I think it's a difference of interpretation in what the OP wants.  The OP, in my reading, wasn't stating the aggregation results were incorrect.  My understanding is that the ordering was not how the OP desired and that the results should be aggregated in the same way and then ordered.  **In one query**